# permission to change web.config in window azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I deploy my application in azure successfully.In some case I have write some thing in my web.config file.But when I try to write in web.config I got permission problem.In local I have not any problem after give read/write permission  to IIS User.
I search but unable to find any thing about read/write permission in azure.

Is there any way to give permission to read/write  in web.config file.Or I am totally in wrong way.Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. Don't change the web.config file from inside the role because all the changes will be lost once the role or any of its instances is redeployed (which can happen for a number of reasons including a VM crash and later automatic recovery initiated by Azure platform).